# What cheese might compliment New England clam chowder?

Tags: bread, cheese, soup, seafood

I have recently become enamored of breadbowls. Not the San Francisco sourdough bowls that they serve on the Wharf; I like to make a basic French or pizza dough and form it over inverted bowls, cover with another bowl, fill the tins with beans and bake in 400°F oven, removing the top bowl after about 10 minutes to let inside crust brown a bit.

I made creamy minestrone the other night, then lined the bottom of one of my bowls with a slice of provolone, heated it in the oven until the cheese was just starting to bubble, then I removed it to let the cheese set a bit. The cheese helped prevent the soup from soaking through, and it was delicious as well.

So, my question: I’d like to do the same thing with a New England clam chowder, but what kind of cheese would compliment the chowder? I was thinking maybe Monterey Jack might be mild enough.

Answer (score 1):

"Compliment" doesn't mean "unobtrusive".

The cheese isn't going to mix all that well with the soup unless it's ladled in while it's still boiling.  I'd actually go with something sharper, so you can refresh the palate after a creamy, heavier soup.

As it's typical practice to select cheeses from the same region as the dish is from, for New England clam chowder I'd go with a sharp Vermont cheddar.